# Not able to get data (node.js) from my client (react.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm not able to retrieve the data I'm sending from the client to the server.

My react code is the following:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/post-entry', { data: formData })
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

My server code is the following:

```
app.post('/post-entry', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.data, "res.body.data here");
});
```

When it reaches the post on my server, the log is `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `formData` is a JS object, just `axios.post('http://localhost:5000/post-entry', formData)` is enough.
You can access this object on server side by `req.body`. But ExpressJS needs a middleware to parse request bodies. You have to use `app.use(express.json())` or `app.use(bodyParser.json())` where bodyParser is `body-parser`.